# How to use multithreads in java so that they take turns in a game

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Trying to use n number of threads, where there are two different types of thread that needs to be being swapped between. So goes t1, x1, t2, x2, t3, x3.... where x and t are thread classes. I've been trying to use wait and notify but cant seem to get this to work. Or synchronisation.

All threads all need to access and modify the same list-array in their respective "turns" which i thought could be its own synchronised class, yet maybe an atomic variable would work also?

Any help is very appreciated.

"""

```
public String startGame(int threadNumbers, List<String> result, String fileLoc) throws IOException {
        Players[] playerThreads = new Players[threadNumbers];
        Card[] cardThreads = new Card[threadNumbers];
        cardDeck cardD = new cardDeck(fileLoc);

        for (int i = 0; i < (threadNumbers); i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                playerThreads[i] = new Players(i+1, cardD);
                if (i>0) {
                    playerThreads[i-1].next = cardThreads[i-0];
                }
                if (i==threadNumbers-1) {
                    playerThreads[i].next = cardThreads[0];
                }
                cardThreads[i] = new Card(i+1);
                if (i>0) {
                    cardThreads[i-1].next = playerThreads[i-0];
                }
                if (i==threadNumbers-1) {
                    cardThreads[i].next = playerThreads[0];
                }



            new Thread(playerThreads[i]).start();
            new Thread(cardThreads[i]).start();
            Thread.yield();
            Thread.yield();
        }
        synchronized (playerThreads[0]) {
            playerThreads[0].notify();
```

"""

This is not working, but what needs to happen is they take a card from the deck in a looping way then start the game after they have a hand. The card threads also are just hands but are different as they dont "play" but just work.

Comment: Yeah with n amount of threads and only one being able to play a turn at a time, there will be lots of waiting

Comment: What instructions/code is theoretically running in each thread?

Comment: @jh6, Right. So what's the point of using different threads? If you want to model a sequence of things happening, why not just have one thread that does each of the things in sequence?

Comment: One reason why I _would_ use threads in a multi-player simulation would be to simulate the _thinking_ that a player does when it's _not_ their turn.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be all in one (JVM) process, there's no need for multiple threading here: Just use a queue to track whose turn it is and who's turn it is next. After a player's turn, add them back to the end of the queue.

And actually, now that I think about it there's no reason this same solution couldn't work with multiple processes or over sockets.

Just use a queue

-- Edit --

So what you need is a class with a blocking method. For example

```
public class Player implements Runnable {
  private Move nextMove;

  public Move synchronized getMove() {
    if (!nextMove) {
      this.wait([add timeout if appropriate]);
    }
    Move next = nextMove;
    nextMove = null;
    return next;
  }

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep([someRandomTime]);
      synchronized(this) {
        if (nextMove == null) {
          nextMove = new Move();
          this.notify();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So still using your queue, you go through each Player and call getMove(), which will block until the player posts a move.

BTW, this kind of blocking is similar to how InputStream.read(buffer) works in sockets. The thread calling read waits until the other side of the stream sends some content.

-- Edit 2 --

And just as a reminder: Don't use synchronized, wait, notify or notifyAll on a Thread object.

Comment: Queue woul definatly be the way i would do this problem, if it werent specified to be multithreaded. Which really puts a spanner in the works